# Invalid signature returned when previewing 7digital track

Tags: 7digital

I am attempting to preview a track via the 7digital api. I have utilised the reference app to test the endpoint here:-

http://7digital.github.io/oauth-reference-page/

I have specified what I consider to be the correct format query, as in:-

http://previews.7digital.com/clip/8514023?oauth_consumer_key=MY_KEY&country=gb&oauth_nonce=221946762&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1&oauth_timestamp=1456932878&oauth_version=1.0&oauth_signature=c5GBrJvxPIf2Kci24pq1qD31U%2Bs%3D

and yet, regardless of what parameters I enter I always get an invalid signature as a response. I have also incorporated this into my javascript code using the same oauth signature library as the reference page and yet still get the same invalid signature returned.
Could someone please shed some light on what I may be doing incorrectly?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to sign it using:

- url = http://previews.7digital.com/clip/8514023
- valid consumer key & consumer secret
- field 'country' = 'GB'

Your query strings parameters look a bit out of order. For OAuth the base string, used to sign, is meant to be in alphabetical order, so country would be first in this case. Once generated it doesn't matter the order in the final request, but the above tool applies them back in the same order (so country is first).

Can you make sure there aren't any spaces around your key/secret? It doesn't appear to strip white space.

If you have more specific problems it may be best to get in touch with 7digital directly - https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/7digital-api

Comment: That works great now that the order is correct, thanks a lot!